# Positioning div to the bottom of another div and optimizing for mobile

Tags: html, css

Simply put, I am somewhat struggling to position a div at the bottom (on the floor) of another. `position: absolute` just makes the div overflow the page!

Here's how I want each block to look:

[image]

I've nearly got there (nearly!), but the content in the white div, is positioned at the top:

```css
.span4.widget-span.widget-type-custom_widget {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
}

.cta-text {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.clearfix.cta-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
}

.cta-wrapper p a {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #f4a244;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget " style="" data-widget-type="custom_widget" data-x="0" data-w="4">
  <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
    <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1523442726463138" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="custom_widget"><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper" style="background-image:url('https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/169013/Email/Template/ty-cta.png?t=1523436793010');">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <h4>Article title goes here lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhonc us tellus non.</h4>
            <div class="fake-button"><a href="#"></a><p><a href="#"></a><a href="#" target="_blank">Read more</a></p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</span></div>
  <!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div>
<div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget " style="" data-widget-type="custom_widget" data-x="0" data-w="4">
  <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
    <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1523442726463138" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="custom_widget"><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper" style="background-image:url('https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/169013/Email/Template/ty-cta.png?t=1523436793010');">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <h4>Article title goes here lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhonc us tellus non.</h4>
            <div class="fake-button"><a href="#"></a><p><a href="#"></a><a href="#" target="_blank">Read more</a></p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</span></div>
  <!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div>
<div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget " style="" data-widget-type="custom_widget" data-x="0" data-w="4">
  <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
    <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1523442726463138" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="custom_widget"><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper" style="background-image:url('https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/169013/Email/Template/ty-cta.png?t=1523436793010');">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <h4>Article title goes here lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhonc us tellus non.</h4>
            <div class="fake-button"><a href="#"></a><p><a href="#"></a><a href="#" target="_blank">Read more</a></p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</span></div>
  <!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div>
```

I need all three of them to appear on one row when screen is full sized, (how it appears now):

[image]

Then when the screen resizes (to mobile), I want one to appear, then another below it (so on). How it appears now on mobile:

Any help/advice would be appreciated!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

If so, you were almost there.

You were basically missing two things:

1. Positioning at the bottom using `position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 5%;`. To make this work, you need to make sure the parent container is positioned, which means it has a different value for `position` than the default `static`. That's why I gave it `position: relative;`.
2. You need a so-called media query to change styles based on viewport width. I adjusted your parent container to take full width if viewport has less than 481px width.

```css
.span4.widget-span.widget-type-custom_widget {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 31%;
  text-align: center;
  /* changed styles after this */
  position: relative;
}

/* adjustment for mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .span4.widget-span.widget-type-custom_widget {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
}

.cta-text {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  /* changed styles after this */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5%;
}

.clearfix.cta-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
}

.cta-wrapper p a {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #f4a244;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget " style="" data-widget-type="custom_widget" data-x="0" data-w="4">
  <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
    <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1523442726463138" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="custom_widget"><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper" style="background-image:url('https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/169013/Email/Template/ty-cta.png?t=1523436793010');">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <h4>Article title goes here lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhonc us tellus non.</h4>
            <div class="fake-button"><a href="#"></a><p><a href="#"></a><a href="#" target="_blank">Read more</a></p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</span></div>
  <!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div>
<div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget " style="" data-widget-type="custom_widget" data-x="0" data-w="4">
  <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
    <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1523442726463138" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="custom_widget"><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper" style="background-image:url('https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/169013/Email/Template/ty-cta.png?t=1523436793010');">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <h4>Article title goes here lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhonc us tellus non.</h4>
            <div class="fake-button"><a href="#"></a><p><a href="#"></a><a href="#" target="_blank">Read more</a></p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</span></div>
  <!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div>
<div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget " style="" data-widget-type="custom_widget" data-x="0" data-w="4">
  <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
    <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1523442726463138" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="custom_widget"><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper" style="background-image:url('https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/169013/Email/Template/ty-cta.png?t=1523436793010');">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <h4>Article title goes here lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhonc us tellus non.</h4>
            <div class="fake-button"><a href="#"></a><p><a href="#"></a><a href="#" target="_blank">Read more</a></p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</span></div>
  <!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.widget-span {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.widget-span .cta-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.cta-text {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.cta-wrapper p a {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #f4a244;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* this media query is form mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .widget-span {
    width: 100%;padding: 0 0 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget " style="" data-widget-type="custom_widget" data-x="0" data-w="4">
  <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
    <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1523442726463138" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="custom_widget"><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper" style="background-image:url('https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/169013/Email/Template/ty-cta.png?t=1523436793010');">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <h4>Article title goes here lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhonc us tellus non.</h4>
            <div class="fake-button"><a href="#"></a><p><a href="#"></a><a href="#" target="_blank">Read more</a></p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</span></div>
  <!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div>
<div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget " style="" data-widget-type="custom_widget" data-x="0" data-w="4">
  <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
    <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1523442726463138" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="custom_widget"><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper" style="background-image:url('https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/169013/Email/Template/ty-cta.png?t=1523436793010');">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <h4>Article title goes here lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhonc us tellus non.</h4>
            <div class="fake-button"><a href="#"></a><p><a href="#"></a><a href="#" target="_blank">Read more</a></p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</span></div>
  <!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div>
<div class="span4 widget-span widget-type-custom_widget " style="" data-widget-type="custom_widget" data-x="0" data-w="4">
  <div class="cell-wrapper layout-widget-wrapper">
    <span id="hs_cos_wrapper_module_1523442726463138" class="hs_cos_wrapper hs_cos_wrapper_widget hs_cos_wrapper_type_custom_widget" style="" data-hs-cos-general-type="widget" data-hs-cos-type="custom_widget"><div class="clearfix cta-wrapper" style="background-image:url('https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/169013/Email/Template/ty-cta.png?t=1523436793010');">
        <div class="cta-text">
            <h4>Article title goes here lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhonc us tellus non.</h4>
            <div class="fake-button"><a href="#"></a><p><a href="#"></a><a href="#" target="_blank">Read more</a></p></div>
        </div>
</div>


</span></div>
  <!--end layout-widget-wrapper -->
</div>
```